# Why can't I resolve a polygon address on etherscan but I can do so on poygonscan?

Tags: ether, addresses, polygon

The question is pretty much in the title.
As I understand it, all EVM compatible chains have the same address space.
And if you have an address on Ethereum you also have it on the other ones.
Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: No, you're perfectly right. Can you clarify what you mean exactly by "resolve a polygon address on etherscan/polygonscan"?

Comment: yeah, but not necessarily the user will create an account on all the chains , and you need to send a transaction for that

Comment: I mean that I looked up an address on polygonscan and did find an entry for it. On etherscan the same address did not return anything.

Comment: Update. Now it was possible. I am confused.

Comment: Because they have been active on Polygon but not Ethereum ...

Comment: @rajohs Etherescan/polygonscan are closed source third party block explorers. Sometimes they add additional features because that benefit their users. On chain ENS resolution depends on the platform supported by ENS team.